# How to know which button is clicked on jsp

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsp, servlets

Jsp with two buttons

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <body style="background-color:black;">


<p>
<p><input type="button" name="good" value="Pen" onclick="location.href='hello';"> </p>
<p><input type="button" name="good" value="Paper" onclick="location.href='hello';">
</p>

</body> 
</html>
```

This is the servlet

```
package pack.exp;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreService;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceFactory;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.EntityNotFoundException;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.KeyFactory;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet 
{

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws 
    IOException 
{
    String val=req.getParameter("good");  
    if("Pen".equals(val))
    {  
        resp.setContentType("text/plain");
        resp.getWriter().println("Pen was clicked" ); 
    }  
    else if("Paper".equals(val))
    {
        resp.setContentType("text/plain");
        resp.getWriter().println("Paper was clicked"); 
    }  

}
 }
```

My code is not giving the  correct output on clicking the buttons. I want when i click Pen then it should enter in if() and print the text and i want same for the paper button.

Answer (score 1):

write this code in jsp, it will be helpful to you

```
 <html>
 <body style="background-color:black;">

 <p><form method="post" action="hello">
 <p><input type="submit" name="good" value="Pen" > </p>
 <p><input type="submit" name="good" value="Paper" >
 </p></form>

 </body> 
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add two  hidden field.

```
<form id="my form" >
 <input type="hidden" name="myPen" />
 <input type="hidden" name="myPaper" />
 <input type="button" name="good" value="pen" on click="{document.myform.mypen.value=this.value;location.href='hello';}"
 <input type="button" name="good" value="paper" on click=" {document. myform. mypaper.value=this.value;location. href='hello';}" />
</form>
```

In Servlet

```
  String val=req.getParameter('mypen'); 
  String val1=req.getParameter("mypaper");
```

At time there is only one value other is `null`. You can do this with `null check`.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery to do your task.

Change your html code to these lines of code.

```
<form method="post" action="#" name="Form" id="Form" >
<input type="button" value="one" id="One"/> 
<input type="button" value="two" id="Two"/>
</form>
```

And add these lines in your script

```
$('input:button').click(function() {
 alert($(this).val());
 var value=$(this).val();
 var url='hello?good=';
 url+=value;
 $("#Form").attr("action",url); 
 $("#Form").submit();   
});
```

You can use jQuery 1.7.1 and above.

Comment: Hey i have no knowledge of JQuery. Can u please explain in html only.

Comment: If you want to use only html, you need to use radio buttons. I am not sure if there is other way.

jquery is easy to use. You jus copy paste my jquery code into script tag of html. 

for reference you can refer a sample jquery example.

[jquery example Click Me](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_hide) follow this link.

Answer (score -1):

Encode the button's value into button's name.

In HTML:

```
<p><input type="button" name="good:Pen" onclick="location.href='hello';"> </p>
<p><input type="button" name="good:Paper" onclick="location.href='hello';">
```

In servlet: iterate over all parameters, look for parameter which `startsWith("good")` and if yes, subtrack the prefix `good:`. If there are no other submit buttons in your page, you can simply name your buttons just `Pen` and `Paper` and check the presence of these parameters as well. There is no javascript needed for this task.